# Android: Pulling the Location at Regular Intervals crashing, Looper Prepare (Yes I searched!!)

Tags: android, multithreading, location, handler, looper

I am trying to pull the Location at regular intervals and send it over the network.  Before doing that I feel it's important to verify that I am pulling the location correctly!  To do that I attempt to pull the location and send a Message to a Handler which displays it on the screen.  I searched all over and in fact used a very useful code segment on stack overflow (Thank you very much!) [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655)

Heres some code:

MyLocation (From the example):

```
package com.Locator;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
Timer timer1;
LocationManager lm;
LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gps_enabled=false;
boolean network_enabled=false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult=result;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
    try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;

    if(gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
         if(gps_enabled)
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         if(network_enabled)
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

         //if there are both values use the latest one
         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             else
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }

         if(gps_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             return;
         }
         if(net_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }
         locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
}
```

Now when I use it like this it works fine (the following is code in the Main activity class):

```
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();



    LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(final Location location){
           Message m = new Message();
           m.obj = location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLattitude();
           threadHandler.sendMessage(m);
        }
    };
```

However I want to do this in regular intervals so I have something like this (The following code is in the main activity class, this time implementing Runnable):

```
....
new Thread(this).start();
....

public void run() {
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();



    LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(final Location location){
           Message m = new Message();
           m.obj = "SDFSDF";
           threadHandler.sendMessage(m);
        }
    };

    while(true) {

        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
        try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
}
}
```

NOTE: threadHandler is of type MyHandler as defined by:

```
class MyHandler extends Handler{

private TextView threadModifiedText;
public MyHandler(TextView tv) {
    threadModifiedText = tv;
}

 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // whenever the Thread notifies this handler we have
        // only this behavior
        threadModifiedText.setText((CharSequence)msg.obj);
 }
}
```

I am getting errors about writing to a Handler from a thread that has not called Looper.prepare().  I have tried adding Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() in various parts of my activity and thread to no avail.  I have tried using a timer instead of a run() + sleep().

Later on instead of writing to a thread handler I am going to insert the location into a queue.  Another thread which handles socket connections will check the emptiness of the queue.  If it has an element it will dequeue() and send it away.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you did not find out. The looper should be out of the while and you should reinitialize myLocation before each new call. However in that case, the timer in the MyLocation class will prevent this to work. So if you remove the getLastLocation part it should work fine in your service. I guess if you want to send locations of a regular basis you rather want to be accurate and you don't care if it takes 30 more seconds, so it's not a bad approach anyway. However you mat want to to do something (open the prefs) if exceptions are thrown when gps and network are not enabled

Good luck.

```
Looper.prepare();   

while(true) {
    myLocation = new MyLocatiom()
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
    try {Thread.sleep(30000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

Looper.loop()
  }
```